# Show list of objects in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am having the following JTable model:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel{

    private String[] columnNames = {"Name", "BornDate", "Salary", "Age", "City"};

    private List<Person> personList;

    public TableModel(List<Person> personList){
        this.personList=personList;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return personList.size();
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public List<Person> getpersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void setPersonList(List<Person> personList) {
        this.personList = personList;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void setPerson(Person sb){
        personList.add(sb);
        fireTableRowsInserted(personList.size()-1, personList.size()-1);
    }

    @Override 
    public String getColumnName(int index) { 
        return columnNames[index]; 
    } 

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public String[] getColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    public void setColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames;
    }
}
```

I want to give `JTable` my list of data objects to display my data. I know that I could transform them into `Object[][]` to populate the data. However, I would like to do that over my table model?

Is there an elegant way to put my data over the TableModel in a JTable?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it you have not implemented your **getValueAt** method. This is the key to getting values which will populate your table cells.

Your implementation should look something like this :

```
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {

    Person person = personList.get(row);
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        return person.getName();
    case 1:
        return person.getBorndate();
    case 2:
        return person.getSalary();
    case 3:
        return person.getAge();
    case 4:
        return person.getCity();
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to call this method in my gui or is this method automatically called from my JTable implementation?

Comment: replace your getValue method that returns null with this method. It should work, give or take a typo

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the fetch logic of Person Fileds inside your TableModel.

```
public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private List<Person> people;

    private static final int DATA = 0;

    private static final int NAME = 1;

    private static final int SURNAME = 2;

    private static final int AGE = 3;

    private static final String[] columns = new String[]{"Date", "Name", "Surname", "Age"};

    private static final Class<?>[] clazz = {Date.class, String.class, String.class, Integer.class};

    public PersonTableModel(List<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;

    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return people.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return columns[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return clazz[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Person a = getPerson(rowIndex);

        if(a != null) {
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case DATA:
                    return a.getData().toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
                case NAME:
                    return a.getName();
                case SURNAME:
                    return a.getSurname();
                case AGE:
                    return a.getAge();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    public Person getPerson(int rowIndex) {
        if (getRowCount() > rowIndex && rowIndex >= 0) {
            return people.get(rowIndex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The method getValueAt is called automatically by the Table!

Comment: The method is called automatically by the Table! (I can't respond directly to your answer)